# Why are electromagnetic fields in free space (isotropic and homogeneous) constant over all time and space?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, waveguide

I see very often that electric and magnetic fields ($\mathbb{R}^3$) in free space are assumed to have the form:

$$\vec{E}=\vec{E}_0{(x,y)}\exp{[i(wt-kz)]}$$
$$\vec{H}=\vec{H}_0{(x,y)}\exp{[i(wt-kz)]}$$

that is, $\vec{E}$ and $\vec{H}$ are propagating along the z-axis and are harmonic in t and z coordinates (**why?**)

Then, to solve the wave equation for the free space they usually say "*consider solutions in free spaces, that is no boundaries conditions, then since space is isotropic and homogeneous $\vec{E}$ and $\vec{H}$ must be **constant over all time and all space***" then the equation:
$$
\nabla ^2\vec{E}=\mu \epsilon \frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}\vec{E}_0{(x,y)}\exp{[i(wt-kz)]}
$$

will have for example
$$
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}E_{0x}(x,y)= \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}E_{0y}(x,y)=0
$$

then when the wave is confined to a wave guide this changes somehow and I cannot understand why the fields are constant in free space.  What changes when we have a guided wave?

Comment: ""then since space is isotropic and homogeneous $\vec{E}$ and $\vec{H}$ must be **constant over all time and all space**"  That is not true. (I'm curious to know where you saw it.) Counter examples: laser beam, light from the sun ... It is *only* true for the plane wave as @anna v has pointed out.   And plane waves are not physical, they are idealizations useful for calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Differential equations have an infinity of solutions which when used for modeling data need the specific situation for bounds, in order to pick up those solutions that fit the data, and in engineering, one solution only.

In your discussion, the terms "isotropic and homogeneous over all space time" pick a subset from the infinity of solutions, which describes well plain waves .

The term "the wave is confined to a guide" imposes boundary conditions that pick up different solutions of the differential equation which can fit  guided waves.

From the infinity of possible solutions of a set of differential equations, those solutions are chosen which fit observations.

Comment: but do isotropic and homogeneous imply constant electromagnetic fields? As far as I know isotropic and homogeneous has to do with $\mu$ and $\epsilon$ being constant over all space

Comment: They are the boundary conditions that give the "constant" electromagnetic solutions of the differential equations. they are alternate boundary conditions, "isotropic and homogeneous" to $μ$  and  $ε$ being constant.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, the E and H you wrote above are assuming the variation along z to be in the form of phase change, i.e. propagation along z. This is then assumed to be a "known". The quest is now to get the formula for the variation with (x,y).

If you have unbounded propagation in isotropic and homogenous media, then the media is symmetric everywhere. There is no physical reason to distinguish a "direction" from another. So, it is reasonable to assume constant wave amplitude and phase along x and y.

Also, Be aware that "constant" in your quoted phrase means w.r.t (x and y).

However, in waveguides, this symmetry along x and y is perturbed by the waveguide walls which force boundary conditions on the wave value. Hence, the solution changes.